# What are the open source projects out there that is built with the pyramid project?

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm learning pyramid. I'd like to see me some open source projects and get a quick start.

Comment: Websites are rarely open source.

Comment: The best you can probably do, since Pyramid's site doesn't have a "Who is using it" section, is: https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=pyramid&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at [shootout](https://github.com/Pylons/shootout), a pretty complete Pyramid demo app.